# the mystery of the table showing up in the subscription, but not in the publication

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, scripting, dmv

TL;DR: This question refer to sql server 2016, transactional replication

I've got a table that shows up in the `subscription` but not in the `publication`.

Here are the details:

---

In one of my servers in the USA I have a publication called `ORCA_Repl_Pub`.

In one of my servers in Europe I have a subscription (you guessed right: `Orca_Repl_Sub`) to the `ORCA_Repl_Pub` publication.

My issue is with table `dbo.repl_application`.

On the publisher I have a look at the articles and it is not there, you can see it is unchecked on the picture below:

[image]

or the same when I go to my `publication_db` and run the following:

```
sp_helpsubscription
```

or the following query has the same effect:

```
select  
db_name() PublisherDB 
, sp.name as PublisherName 
, sa.name as TableName 
, UPPER(srv.srvname) as SubscriberServerName 
from dbo.syspublications sp  
join dbo.sysarticles sa on sp.pubid = sa.pubid 
join dbo.syssubscriptions s on sa.artid = s.artid 
join master.dbo.sysservers srv on s.srvid = srv.srvid
```

[image]

But then when I check on the `subscriber_db` side, on the `subscriber server`, by running the following query, to find out everything possible about the table `dbo.repl_application` I get:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    dbo.MSreplication_objects R
        INNER JOIN sys.objects so 
                ON r.object_name = so.name 
               AND so.type = 'P' --stored procedures

        INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies dp 
                ON so.object_id = dp.referencing_id

        INNER JOIN sys.objects ot 
                ON dp.referenced_id = ot.object_id  
               AND r.article = ot.name
where r.article = 'repl_application'
```

I have broken the picture down in 3 pieces for it to fit here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Basically everything seems to be correct!!!

and using some magic I can see that the table in question has been used, as you can see on the picture below (the date of posting `is 14-aug-2019`:

[image]

So the question is:

how and why this `repl_application` is in the `subscription` but not in the `publication`?

I think it might be:

1. because on a previous version of that `publication` it was there, and as we deployed a new system, that table was no longer included.

But what about the table creation date and the last table update time, and last time the table was read?

2. the database was not wiped out completely or the `subscription` was not 100% dropped and that table remained with a reference on [dbo.MSreplication_objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/msreplication-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Either way, all is working fine, I just would love to know if I could find out on the `subscription` side, if there is any indication anywhere, that that table should not be showing up.

so, if you have any ideas regarding that, please let me know and I will dig around it.